# How to filter to something on a specific date in DAX

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, dax

I am trying to get a rolling 12 revenue figure for active clients filterable by quarter and year. My current function uses a Quarter Index to calculate for the past 12 months. Here it is.

```
Rev R12 12 = 
VAR _lastq = MAX('RCB Core Revenue'[Quarter Index])
VAR _firstq = _lastq - 4
VAR _activemax = IF(MAX(
VAR _res = CALCULATE(
SUM('RCB Core Revenue'[Revenue]), 'RCB Core Revenue'[Active vs Deconverted] = "Active",
FILTER(ALL(_QuarterEndTable), '_QuarterEndTable'[Quarter Index] > _firstq && '_QuarterEndTable'[Quarter Index] <= _lastq))
RETURN _res
```

The basic outline of this seems to work relatively well, but the issue I'm having is that It's adding up the revenue for clients that were active in any/all 4 quarters in the rolling 12 when I only want the active filter to be applied to the max quarter in the function. For example, if I pick Q4 2023, I only want to see clients that were active in that specific quarter rather than clients that were active throughout the entire 12 month period.

I figured out that the issue is most likely due to the ALL() function in my calculation, so I was trying to find something that allowed me to filter on multiple variables at once. For example, keep the ALL() but then stipulate that the "active" filter only be applied to the max quarter in the range.

Answer (score 0):

probably an easier way to do this but you could add a var for the selected quarter and add a filter on res like this:

```
Rev R12 12 = 
VAR _lastq = MAX('RCB Core Revenue'[Quarter Index])
VAR _firstq = _lastq - 4
VAR _selQrt = SELECTEDVALUE(QUARTER DIMENSION THAT USERS SELECT)
VAR revQrt = CALCULATE(Sum(rcb core rev[revenue]),quarter dimension = _selQRT)
--VAR _activemax = IF(MAX( -- not sure what this var is doing
VAR _res = CALCULATE(
SUM('RCB Core Revenue'[Revenue]), 'RCB Core Revenue'[Active vs Deconverted] = "Active",
FILTER(ALL(_QuarterEndTable), '_QuarterEndTable'[Quarter Index] > _firstq && '_QuarterEndTable'[Quarter Index] <= _lastq && reQrt > 0))
RETURN _res
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this, and it's still not giving me the right number. And now, when I pick a year or don't pick anything at all, the card shows up as blank.